# AttributeRouting ActionLink helper rendering query string value instead of including parameter in route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am working on my first MVC project and using attribute routing within my controllers.  I am having a slight issue with one of my actions which has two possible route paths.  The routes themselves are working but the actionLinks being generated are not to my liking.

**Routes:**

```
    [Route("add")]
    [Route("{parentId:int?}/add")]
```

**ActionLink definition:**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add Category", "Add", "Category", new { parentId = @Model.CurrentCategoryId}, new { @Class = "btn btn-primary"})
```

This works, but when a currentCategoryId is not null the link produced is this:

```
/categories/add?parentId=2
```

but what i would like to see (which is picked up when you hand roll the url) is:

```
/categories/2/add
```

is there anyway i can achieve this with the actionLink or any other MVC magic?

Comment: Looks like this route is getting overrided by the default route in the RouteConfig File. Try out coment that route to see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[Route("add", Order = 2)]
[Route("{parentId:int?}/add", Order = 1)]
```

That still may not work because the fact that you have a route that doesn't require a parameter may short-circuit the routing logic regardless. Another option would be to name each route and then explicitly state the one your want:

```
[Route("add", Name = "AddCategory")]
[Route("{parentId:int?}/add", Name = "AddCategoryForParentId")]
```

Then:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Add Category", "AddCategoryForParentId", new { parentId = @Model.CurrentCategoryId }, ...)
```

Comment: Changing the order worked... Genius that it was something so simple.